# Using Facebook's SHARE button pre-populated texts

Tags: ios, facebook, share

I've read on Facebook's policies that in your SHARE button the messenger's can't be pre-populated at all. No matter if it's a little message or a URL. It must be 100% user generated. Which sucks for the iOS and Android developers because the SHARE button is one of the best ways to market your app. However, in the App store i see a lot of big gaming companies and developers using the Facebook share button with pre-populated texts and URLS. Some of these games are in the top 20 downloaded apps. I can't believe Facebook doesn't see that. Maybe they don't care?

Even though it's against Facebook policy, does Facebook penalize developers for posting pre-populated texts even though those texts can be edited before being posted? Any developer have an experience with this?

Comment: Yes we block and delete app daily that do things against our Platform Policy. If you have examples of big apps doing it please send a message to me with which and I forward it to our Developer Operations team

Comment: I'm not going to throw any developer under the bus, this is Facebook's job. Twitter allows pre-populated posts, Facebook should as well. According to facebook policy it's "convenient" for the user to have an empty messenger they can type out themselves. However, it's not convenient for the user when they need to spend time typing out progress reports. Pre-populated texts truly provide the most convenience because they can be deleted by the user before posting. Everybody wins.

Comment: They don't need to type a message. You can share a url without a message. And Facebook will not change just because Twitter allows it.

Comment: I read in the policies I can't share a URL either.

Comment: You are wrong. You can share a link. You are not allowed to put a link in the message but you can share a link.

Comment: I meant sharing a link in the Facebook SHARE button messenger.

Btw, you wanted an app with a pre-populated text in the SHARE button? Alright, every app in the app store that's a game that has a Facebook share button, has pre-populated message. It's in Game Center's SHARE button. Against Facebook policy, but it's there, you can even check on your iPhone,iPad,iPod touch. It's pre-populated by Apple. It can be deleted before posting. Nothing a developer can do about that.

Comment: Yes you can share a link in messenger. I don't work with enforcing apps but if you give me names I can forward them to the right people

Comment: I told you, EVERY game app in the app store has a pre-populated Facebook share button message. Any game app using Game Center and inside Game Center in Leaderboards there's a share button. When you click on Facebook there's a pre-populated message made by Apple. Game developers can do nothing about permanently deleting that message. So if Apple gets to do it, what's wrong with allowing Apple game developers doing it too?

So I can put a link to the App store where my app is in Facebook Share button messanger for users to share on Facebook?

Comment: So not every game is doing it. Only Apple is doing it inside Game Center. Thanks I will forward that to Developer Operations. As I said it is not ok that anyone is doing it. And yes you can use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#share_dialog . It even have an example of how to share a link. There is also the Share and Send buttons https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#buttons

Comment: Apple is not just anyone, it's the largest company in the world and soon to be the 1st $1 trillion market capitalization company. Facebook won't stop Apple from doing what they want to do. Facebook will make a work-around in your policies that includes allowing Apple to do as they please.

Comment: Ok, you are allowed to believe that. But even if that was the case it still means that you can't do it

Comment: What do you mean by blocking and deleting apps? How can you delete an App from the App store if you're Facebook? So you can't delete apps.  How do you block an app? Do you block the app's Facebook page, or do you block the app from accessing Facebook through the share button?

Comment: We can delete the Facebook App ID so any Facebook integration stops working. We can also block all shares done with your Facebook App ID.

Comment: Last question. If you were to find pre-populated text in the share button and do as you stated, then in an update of the app, with the pre-populated text gone, would Facebook give the developer back the Facebook App ID or make a new one so the share button works again?